# create a hash in an array with values from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

i have firstname,lastname  and id of a list of people in database.
Now i want to make an array like

```
[{
  value: <corresponding id>,
  label: "<corresponding person name>"
 },
 {
  value: <corresponding id>,
  label: "<corresponding person name>"
 },
  ....
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
users = User.all
user_hash_array = users.collect{|user| {:value => user.id, :label => user.firstname}}
```

This will work like following

```
id   firstname   lastname
1    Salil       Gaikwad
2    Nidhin      Bose
```

This will gives you following

```
user_hash_array = [{:value=>1, :label=>"Salil"}, {:value=>2, :label=>"Nidhin"}]
```

Comment: thanks.how can i make it 
value: <corresponding id> unlike
:value => <corresponding id> in your answer

Comment: In Ruby 1.9.3 `{:value=>1} == {value:1}` Try yourself from irb then type `{value:1}` and you will get `{:value=>1}`

Comment: In that case you can't get an hash like above.Just curious why you want such hash?

Comment: i am trying to implement something like this
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/VaKfP/)